# Trigger Google (re)crawl with ping

Tags: google-search, web-crawlers, googlebot, ping

I have a site A with daily updated content. Right after the update, I send a webblog ping using various ping services, like http://rpc.pingomatic.com. Moments later, the updated homepage lands in the Google index, as well as the new page.  Exactly as I want.

Now I want to do the same with site B. But for any reason, the homepage update does not work. Google recrawls the site a day later or so.

Until now I thought, the ping causes Google to recrawl the site. Is that maybe not the case? Did Google figure out its own way to find out when updates happen?

Or does the ping service work for site A but not for B? Can I found out if site B maybe got banned from sending pings?

**TL;DR** Can I *programmatically* tell Google to recrawl my site as soon as possible?

Comment: You cannot ping Google and make it do anything. It does what it does when it does it. Plain and simple. Think about it for a second- if everyone can ping Google, do you think Google would get a second of peace and be able to do it's work at all? Of course not! My suggestion is to be patient and do not make Google mad by telling it to hurry up the hell up. That is not your place to do. If it is critical, the you can use the Fetch as Google in Webmaster Tools. But I recommend restraint using this option. And no(!)- you cannot ping Google regardless of any claim.

Comment: OK, and so you assume that the fast recrawl of my site A just happens by accident right after the update and Pingomatic ping?

Comment: Yes. Just a coincidence. Google does not take commands/instructions from other websites. Google does not give it's power away- at all. You have more control/power to make Google respond to your site more than you think by simply doing good work and building upon signals such as freshness, new content, content quality, user satisfaction, back links, social signals, and so on. These are the only things that influence Google. There is no ping option for Google other than what exists within Google Webmaster Tools.